# MySQL: Get newest entries older than xxx, Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, select, explain

I have a table that looks like so:

```
ID | objectID | time | ...
-------------------
 1 |        1 | ...
 2 |        1 | ...
 3 |        1 | ...
 4 |        2 | ...
 5 |        2 | ...
 6 |        3 | ...
 7 |        4 | ...
```

ID is the primary key, objectID is non-unique.
I am trying to increase performance on a query to get the most recent entries for all objectIDs, but the entries should not be newer than a certain value.
I tried to following two queries, which should both provide the same (and correct results):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE time <= XXX
    ORDER BY time DESC
)
GROUP BY objectID
```

AND

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t     
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX(time)
    FROM table
    WHERE time <= 1353143351
    GROUP BY objectID
) s
USING (ID)
```

An EXPLAIN for the first query tells me

```
id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 145827 | Using temporary; Using filesort
2  | DERIVED     | tbl_test   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 238694 | Using filesort
```

for the second query it says

```
id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 325 
1  | PRIMARY     | t          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ID    | PRIMARY | 4       | s.ID | 1   
2  | DERIVED     | tbl_test   | index  | NULL          | ID      | 12      | NULL | 238694 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

(tbl_test is my table for testing)

The second query seems to be (much) faster, but still not extreme fast with a runtime of 0.1 secs at ~200k DB entries.
Is there a way to increase performance of the query? Any missing indexes?

Thanks in advance!!

**Edit: Explain for eggys query (see query in his post):**

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    325 
1   PRIMARY lab_case_test   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    238694  Using where; Using join buffer
2   DERIVED lab_case_test   index   NULL    ID  12  NULL    238694  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...

CREATE TABLE `lab_case_test` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `caseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
 // ....
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `ID` (`ID`,`caseID`,`time`),
 KEY `caseID` (`caseID`,`time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=238695 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: why do you have an index on all 3 columns?

Answer (score 1):

You want a composite index over `(objectID, time)`:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX (objectID, time)
```

The reason for this is that MySQL can then retrieve the maximum `time` for each `objectID` directly from the index tree; it can then also use the same index in joining against the table again to find the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) records using something like your second query (but one should join on both `objectID` and `time`—I like to use a `NATURAL JOIN` in cases like this):

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   objectID, MAX(time) time
  FROM     my_table
  WHERE    time <= 1353143351
  GROUP BY objectID
) t
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to be a little bit slower than my second query (0.2sec). Also, I read that natural join should be avoided. Greetings

Comment: @schlimpf: To the extent that "*`NATURAL JOIN` should be avoided*", it is because it hides the columns on which joins are performed; should the schema change, it can often lead to unexpected effects (this is similar to why `SELECT *` should be avoided).  However, as with any rule of thumb, there are exceptions: and queries such as this, where the table is joining to a limited version of itself, are (IMHO) just one of those: as any schema change will effect both sides of the join and therefore not give rise to such problems. Indeed, I feel that `NATURAL JOIN` suits such queries extremely well.

Comment: @schlimpf: Was your second query cached?  Can you post the `EXPLAIN` plan for my query?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Still, it seems to be a little bit slower than the `INNER JOIN` version. Edit: I posted the `EXPLAIN` in my first post. How can I check/avoid if the query was cached?

Comment: @schlimpf: Did you create the index as suggested?

Comment: yup did that and I also tried a `RESET QUERY CACHE` before the queries. The `INNER JOIN` is slightly faster

Comment: @schlimpf: The index does not appear to be available to the query optimiser (it is not listing it under `possible_keys` and is most certainly not selecting it for use).  Please verify that it has been created?

Comment: eggyal it has been created. The problem seems to be the inner query. I have observed this behavior before when I tested my `INNER JOIN` query. If I remove the ID from the `SELECT`, the index is used. But obviously it can't be removed for the complete query ;)

Comment: @schlimpf: No, the index is not being used in the derived table; whereas one would expect it to be (and thereby avoid the filesort).  Something doesn't look right here.  Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE lab_case_test`.

Comment: added in the first post. the other index you see was for testing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27130/discussion-between-schlimpf-and-eggyal)